# Garbage collection in C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, garbage-collection

I know garbage collector collects allocated memory when it doesn't find any pointer to an object.
I was wondering if I create and initial some local objects in a loop, are these objects collected by Java garbage collector? What about C#?

If I create and initial some objects in a local function, what would happen to them? Will they collected when running of local function finishes?

I want to know, are local objects exactly like local variables?

Thanks.

Comment: [Garbage Collection in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in a function memory is allocated in the `stack` for non-object variables and when a function completes its execution,  the `stack` is cleared and memory is freed.

For objects, memory is allocated in the `heap` (You will remember `malloc()` and `free()` in **C**). But in **Java** and **C#** , the `free()` function is what the garbage collector does for you instead of you worrying about it.

So even in functions, the objects are local variables but not stored in `stack` but on `heap`. So they are not the same as `int i`. But when the function is completed, those objects are out of scope. So you will no longer have access to them but their memory is not freed until `garbage collector` runs and clears them.

But how a `garbage collector` runs, when it runs is all based on different algorithm. They may not be the same for even different implementations of **Java** (e.g sun java may have different algorithm than another Java implementation)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
So I may go out of memory because of local objects because the time of execution of garbage collector is different.
I know terminating objects and making memory free manually isn't so good, so do you have any suggestion for local objects because I don't like my program goes out of memory.

Comment: Do not worry about that. Thats why garbage collector is available, it will take care of removing unused objects and it does a better job than us :)

Comment: But I feel by creating many local objects, execution of programs will not be optimized in memory use. Am I right?

Comment: no, these languages are well developed. The gc's are well researched and implemented so you can rely on them. Its just like moving from assembly programming to C, the more the language hide the more we tend to not believe it !

Comment: Yea, it's hard to believe them;)
Thanks.